# Docker container immediately exits when started after system reboot

Tags: apache, docker

I'm starting my custom docker container (OpenSuse, PHP, Apache, some add-ons) this way:

1. `docker build --build-arg http_proxy=http://user:pwd@ip:port -t prefix/myapp myapp`
2. `create --name=myapp --hostname=myapp-p 80:80 -v ${PWD}/myapp:/srv/www/myapp prefix/myapp`
3. `docker start myapp`

This works perfectly. I can stop and later start the container. However, if I reboot my host system (Windows 10), I'm not able to start the container again. When I try to, the container immediately exits.

How can this be? As stated above, I use the `-p` and `-v` flags to map ports and mount a directory.

This is the output of...

`docker logs myapp
-> httpd (pid 1) already running`

Comment: Can you include the specific docker commands you're running? This could give us a better idea of what's going on

Comment: Sure. I've updated the original post.

Comment: Please provide output of `docker logs myapp`.

Comment: I'v updated the original post and provided log info. Maybe this has something to do with the apache server that is supposed to run inside the container?

Answer (score 0):

May or may not be your problem (the logs will be telling), but I ran into an issue with docker on windows where the container tries to start before the file system is ready, which causes an error with the volume mounts. I never found a great solution aside from running a task that verifies the volume mount and restarts the container if it failed.